# How to prove that Q \ Z is countable

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, cardinals

The question is asking to prove that Q \ Z is countable. We are allowed to use the fact that Q and N have the same cardinality.

My current idea is to show that there is a bijection between the set Q \ Z and Q and from there use the fact that the composition of the bijections between Q \ Z and Q and Q and N is bijective to show that Q \ Z has the same cardinality as N hence is countable.

However, I'm struggling to think of formally constructing a bijection from Q\Z to Q. Could someone help me with this? Or ss there a better way to do this question

Comment: If you know $\mathbb Q$ is countable, then $\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb Z$ must be at most countable, right? Is it finite?

Comment: Suppose you have a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$. Since $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z})$ is an infinite subset of $ \mathbb{N}$, you can define (it is straightforward to do but messy) by renumbering, a bijection $g : \mathbb{N} \to f^{-1}(\mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z})$.